# Why working code with SVM Linear Kernel not working with RBF

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

When I use **trainAuto** method of SVM, I get the value 2 for `getKernelType()` but when I use the `RBF` in my code, it trains my file and outputs the XML file.

```
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_RBF)
svm.setGamma(0.0025)
svm.setC(0.5)
svm.train(samples, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels)
svm.save('svm_data.xml')
```

Above code works for me. But when I moved to prediction part with below code

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((100,200), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load('svm_data.xml')
sv = svm.getSupportVectors()
rho, alpha, svidx = svm.getDecisionFunction(0)
svm_new = np.append(sv, -rho)
hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)
```

It shows be below error

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) checkDetectorSize() in function 'cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector'
```

But **when I change RBF with LINEAR** it works for me in prediction part.

When I check

```
print (hog.checkDetectorSize())
print (hog.getDescriptorSize())
```

It returns `True` for DetectorSize and `26676` for DescriptorSize

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is unable to accept SVM with other than linear kernel.

First, the [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a09e354ad701f56f9c550dc0385dc36f1) says:

> ***setSVMDetector()***
>
> virtual void cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector    (   InputArray  _svmdetector    )
>
> Parameters
>
> _svmdetector  coefficients for the **linear** SVM classifier.

It is obvious that you only pass to `HOGDescriptor` the coefficients of the SVM (as a single array), but not the *kind* (Linear, RBF and Polynomial are the most common) and/or parameters specific to it (the degree of the polynomial or gamma for RBF). So the underlying OpenCV detector has no way of figuring out kind of the kernel. And it does not have to, because the only one implemented is the linear one.

In addition, read [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/188301/opencv-34-assertion-failed-checkdetectorsize-in-setsvmdetector/) and [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/210153/opencv-assertion-failed-in-function-setsvmdetector/) questions.

Comment: But linear giving not good results at all with HOG though it should be

Comment: It means that I have to change `svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)` into Regression with Linear SVM? `SVM.C_SVR_EPS` ?

Comment: I don't think regression/classification mode has some influence on the result here. It is a mater of result interpretation: in one case you get distance from the decision line, in the other you only interested in it's sign. In both cases the alfas would be the same. You can try to change it, but I doubt it will change anything. As for the low performance, make sure that you train on HOG descriptors and not on the raw images [see example](https://answers.opencv.org/question/125970/hog-and-svm-training-and-testing-issues/)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493796/do-i-need-to-calculate-hist-at-prediction-time-in-svm) is how I am training with HOG, this top most code

Answer (score 0):

~/opencv-3.4.16/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp

```
void calc_rbf( int vcount, int var_count, const float* vecs,
               const float* another, Qfloat* results )
{
    double gamma = -params.gamma;
    int j, k;

    for( j = 0; j < vcount; j++ )
    {
        const float* sample = &vecs[j*var_count];
        double s = 0;

        for( k = 0; k <= var_count - 4; k += 4 )
        {
            double t0 = sample[k] - another[k];
            double t1 = sample[k+1] - another[k+1];

            s += t0*t0 + t1*t1;

            t0 = sample[k+2] - another[k+2];
            t1 = sample[k+3] - another[k+3];

            s += t0*t0 + t1*t1;
        }

        for( ; k < var_count; k++ )
        {
            double t0 = sample[k] - another[k];
            s += t0*t0;
        }
        results[j] = (Qfloat)(s*gamma);
    }

    if( vcount > 0 )
    {
        Mat R( 1, vcount, QFLOAT_TYPE, results );
        exp( R, R );
    }
}

//in train_HOG.cpp  
clog << "Training SVM..." << "trained times 1" << endl;
Ptr< SVM > svm = SVM::create();
/* Default values to train SVM */
svm->setCoef0( 0.0 );
svm->setDegree( 3 );
svm->setTermCriteria( TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + TermCriteria::EPS, 1000, 1e-3 ) );
//svm->setGamma( 0 );
//svm->setKernel( SVM::LINEAR );
svm->setKernel( SVM::RBF );
svm->setNu( 0.5 );
svm->setP( 0.1 ); // for EPSILON_SVR, epsilon in loss function?
svm->setC( 0.01 ); // From paper, soft classifier
svm->setType( SVM::EPS_SVR ); // C_SVC; // EPSILON_SVR; // may be also NU_SVR; // do regression task
svm->train( train_data, ROW_SAMPLE, labels );

//kernel RBF comment this
/*CV_Assert( alpha.total() == 1 && svidx.total() == 1 && sv_total == 1 );
CV_Assert( (alpha.type() == CV_64F && alpha.at<double>(0) == 1.) ||
           (alpha.type() == CV_32F && alpha.at<float>(0) == 1.f) );
CV_Assert( sv.type() == CV_32F );*/
```