# Do I need to calculate hist at prediction time in SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

I am training my dataset with the below code:

```
for file in glob.glob('C:\*.png'):
    image = cv2.imread(file, 1)
    image = cv2.resize(img, (60, 120))
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((60,120), (8,8), (4,4), (4,4), 9)
    hist = hog.compute(image)
    samples.append(hist)
    labels.append(-1)
```

I am using `hist = hog.compute(image)`. This code is in the training part, but when I do the prediction part:

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((60,120), (8,8), (4,4), (4,4), 9)
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load('svm_data.xml')
sv = svm.getSupportVectors()
rho, alpha, svidx = svm.getDecisionFunction(0)
svm_new = np.append(sv, -rho)
hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)
```

I am not using `hist = hog.compute(image)`, and my results are not as good. Do I need to use hog.compute in prediction part while using `Multiscale`?

```
found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img,hitThreshold=0,winStride=(8,8),padding=(16,16), scale=1.05, finalThreshold = 2.0,useMeanshiftGrouping=False)
```

When I try to use it, it gives an error, and without it, I am not getting good results. Am I doing wrong in the training part or in the prediction part?

Update: Complete code using for training SVM:

```
samples = []
labels = []    
for filename in glob.glob('C:\*.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (160, 320))
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((160,320), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
    hist = hog.compute(img)
    samples.append(hist)
    labels.append(+1)

for file in glob.glob("C:\\*.jpg"):
    img = cv2.imread(file, 0)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (160, 320))
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((160,320), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
    hist = hog.compute(img)
    samples.append(hist)
    labels.append(-1)

# Convert objects to Numpy Objects
samples = np.float32(samples)
labels = np.array(labels)

# Shuffle Samples
rand = np.random.RandomState(321)
shuffle = rand.permutation(len(samples))
samples = samples[shuffle]
labels = labels[shuffle]

# Create SVM classifier
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
# Train
svm.train(samples, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels)
svm.save('C:\svm_data.xml')
```

Code using for Prediction:

```
sample=[]
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((160,320), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load('C:\svm_data.xml')
sv = svm.getSupportVectors()
rho, alpha, svidx = svm.getDecisionFunction(0)
svm_new = np.append(sv, -rho)
hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)

for file in glob.glob("C:\\Test\\*.jpg"): 
    img = cv2.imread(file, 0) 
    img = cv2.resize(img, (160, 320))
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((160,320), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img,hitThreshold=0,winStride=(8,8),padding=(16,16), scale=1.05, finalThreshold = 2.0,useMeanshiftGrouping=False)
   for (x, y, w, h) in found:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
   cv2.imshow("Image", img)
   cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, all the samples belong to the same class:

```
labels.append(-1)
```

Your SVM classifier can't learn anything from this. You need to present to SVM both positive examples (labeled as 1) and negative ones (usually labeled as 0 or -1). It would be helpful if your dataset is balanced: that is amount of positive and negative images is roughly the same.

After your SVM is trained properly, and `hog` is made aware of it (by `hog.setSVMDetector()`) using `hog.detectMultiScale()` or `hog.detect()` will "automatically" report positive matches. It combines two operation: calculates HOG descriptors and classifies them using provided SVM. In addition `hog.detectMultiScale()` automatically increases the image and optionally groups the overlapped detections.

Now why you need `hog.compute(image)` on the training phase: this calculates raw HOG descriptors. This is the input to your classifier. Those descriptors is just a bunch of numbers calculated in specific way, and by themselves do not indicate if there is an object that you are looking for in the image. To make this decision, you need some kind of a classifier, and SVM is just a possible choice. You do not have to use it, it just usually produces very good results, and is included as a default.

**Update** 
See how prediction is done in the OpenCV [example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/peopledetect.py):

Comment: I updated the question with code, I am doing the +1 part, I only added -1 part in my code, My dataset is balanced, both negative and positive are 1500.

Comment: Codes are running fine but results are not good at all, approx 0%, that's why I am asking if I need to work somewhere on `hog.compute(image)`

Comment: The answer is still no. Your code **looks** ok. May be the objects you searching for are too complex. Try following: after shuffling the samples, take first 80% of your data and train your SVM. On the rest run `svm.predict()`. Compare the results with the labels. It will show you how good your classifier is.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `hist` ? If it is not a one dimensional vector, you should use `.ravel()`

Comment: I am us8ng '.ravel()' its just not in above code. Cause i tried without ravel as well. I am detecting eye brow.

Comment: I am using Multiscale so i cam get the rectangle around the detected object. Thats creating the problem. If check the result in form of -1 and 1, result is fair enough without 'multiscale' but with multiscale result is 0

Comment: That's strange. Try dropping `hitThreshold=0`. This overrides your  `rho`.  BTW you override weights from detection in line `for (x, y, w, h) in found`.

Comment: Yes but what option i have other than `for (x, y, w, h) in found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198122/discussion-between-igrinis-and-ahf).